# Why doesn't my thermostat work?

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I replaced old thermostat with Honeywell wifi and added C wire from furnace to new thermostat. I left the jumper wire on Rc and R in place and wifi would not come on line. Checked C wire and have 28vdc from C to R. The C wire is grounded to furnace just as it's supposed to be. The old thermostat does not have a C wire or Rc terminal. It is a Trane XT300C thermostat. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm confused. In your first sentence you said you replaced your old thermostat with a Honeywell. At the end you say it's a Trane.

Comment: Side note:  HVAC control systems typically use Alternating Current (VAC), not Direct Current (VDC).

Comment: Although the voltage between the `R` wire and the furnace frame might read 28V, you have to attach the `C` wire to the neutral lead of the 24VAC side of transformer feeding the furnace control board.